# Why is the expectation value of $\partial( \hat x \hat p)\over \partial t$ equal to 0 even when the state is time dependent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I would like to show that the expectation value of $\partial( \hat x \hat p)\over \partial t$ is $0$ for some arbitrary state vector

but it seems to me that this is true only when $\Psi$ is in stationary states, i.e. time-independent, due to

$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left( \hat O \ \psi \right) = \frac{\partial \hat O}{\partial t} \psi + \hat O  \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} = 0$ if both $\hat O $ and $\Psi $ are time independent.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's true for an arbitrary state, say, because of the correspondence principle.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/329553)

Comment: @JohnRennie : I respectfully disagree. As average $xp$ is not necessarily constant in time in classical mechanics, the average in the question cannot be always constant in quantum mechanics due to the correspondence principle.